# Extract Images with text from PDF and Edit it using iTextSharp

Tags: vb.net, itext

I am trying to do following things in Windows Forms
1) Read a PDF in Windows Forms
2) Get the Images with Text in it 
3) Color / fill the Image 
4) save everything to a new file

I have tried [Problem with PdfTextExtractor in itext!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704518/problem-with-pdftextextractor-in-itext)
But It didn't help.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
 Public Shared Sub ExtractImagesFromPDF(sourcePdf As String, outputPath As String)
    'NOTE:  This will only get the first image it finds per page.'
    Dim pdf As New PdfReader(sourcePdf)
    Dim raf As RandomAccessFileOrArray = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray(sourcePdf)

    Try
        For pageNumber As Integer = 1 To pdf.NumberOfPages
            Dim pg As PdfDictionary = pdf.GetPageN(pageNumber)

            ' recursively search pages, forms and groups for images.'
            Dim obj As PdfObject = FindImageInPDFDictionary(pg)
            If obj IsNot Nothing Then

                Dim XrefIndex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DirectCast(obj, PRIndirectReference).Number.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                Dim pdfObj As PdfObject = pdf.GetPdfObject(XrefIndex)
                Dim pdfStrem As PdfStream = DirectCast(pdfObj, PdfStream)
                Dim bytes As Byte() = PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw(DirectCast(pdfStrem, PRStream))
                If (bytes IsNot Nothing) Then
                    Using memStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes)
                        memStream.Position = 0
                        Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memStream)
                        ' must save the file while stream is open.'
                        If Not Directory.Exists(outputPath) Then
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath)
                        End If

                        Dim path__1 As String = Path.Combine(outputPath, [String].Format("{0}.jpg", pageNumber))
                        Dim parms As New System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1)
                        parms.Param(0) = New System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, 0)
                        'Dim jpegEncoder As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.GetImageEncoder("JPEG")'

                        img.Save(path__1) 'jpegEncoder, parms'
                    End Using
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Catch
        Throw
    Finally
        pdf.Close()
        raf.Close()
    End Try


End Sub
```

Now, the actual purpose of this is to get something like this 
[image]

If this is the actual PDF, I will have to check if there any any items in that bin(by Text in that box)

If there are items then I have to color it like below 
[image]

Can someone help me with this

The PDF can be retrieved [here](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/raw/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/Baltimore%20-%20Copy.pdf).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! To get an answer it might be helpful if you could add what you currently get and what isn't working in your code.

Comment: You try to extract bitmap images. Are you sure the bins in your screen shots are bitmap images? Or is it possible that they are vector graphics?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to get any as per the requirements. Because The layout you see in the images are in PDF as an Image format. I would appreciate for any sort of ideas that might help in achieving the solution. The layout is created by some other company with RT systems when we give them the data like bins, racks etc

Comment: From the link http://visual-integrity.com/support/faq/how-can-i-tell-if-my-pdf-file-is-a-vector-or-a-bitmap/  , I can see clearly without any cracked lines of the bins in PDF so I think it is Vector not bitmap images

Comment: In that case your code most likely will not help at all because it seems to look for bitmap images. Unfortunately there are multiple ways one can draw something like your images in PDFs with vector graphics. Thus, can you share a sample PDF for analysis?

Comment: I am new to Stackoverflow. Not sure how to share the PDF file. I tried to send an image of the PDF

Comment: You put your file on a file sharing service like Dropbox or Google Drive and you share the link here. Make sure the file is public.

Comment: I emailed to mkl from the email that was mentioned in his profile

Comment: I shared it on github: [Baltimore - Copy.pdf](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/raw/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/Baltimore%20-%20Copy.pdf)

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse RUPS should be improved to better cope with PDFs like this one with gigantic content streams, e.g. quickly showing the stream without special effects while in the background a colored rendering is generated to eventually replace the simple one.

Comment: @mkl well, feel free to discuss on Slack. :)

Comment: @nysu your question has not being forgotten. Your PDF merely is very special, it has a very huge page content stream, huge enough to make several software packages fail.

Comment: I appreciate for getting back. thank you. that is just one PDF. we have warehouses like that more than 20. The program should be for all the warehouses but I  just want to take baby steps by starting with one location.